# VDM call to get the navigation property which has multiplicity as 0 to 1, gives NullPointerException for 0 response

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I am using VDM to get the navigation property which has multiplicity as 0..1.

Whenever the response returned from S4 is 0 (that is "204 No Content"), I am getting a `NullPointerException`.

```
HeaderCDSForPRForGuidedBuying requisitionHeader = isActiveEntity ? readActivatedHeader(purchaseRequisition) : readHeaderInternal(draftUUID);
    GuidedProcurementDeliveryAddressAtHeader requisitionHeaderAddress;

    requisitionHeaderAddress = requisitionHeader.getGuidedProcmtReqnDelivAddrOrFetch();

    return S4ToGBServiceMapper.mapToRequisitionHeader(requisitionHeader, requisitionHeaderAddress);
```

Here `requisitionHeader.getGuidedProcmtReqnDelivAddrOrFetch();` is the navigation entity which is resulting in "204 No Content" from S4 whenever there are no data.

Metadata of the entity

```
    <EntityType Name="C_GuidedProcmtReqnHdrTPType" sap:label="Header CDS 
     for PR for guided buying" sap:content-version="1">
<Key> 
<PropertyRef Name="PurchaseRequisition"/>
<PropertyRef Name="DraftUUID"/>
<PropertyRef Name="IsActiveEntity"/>
</Key>
<Property Name="Activation_ac" Type="Edm.Boolean" sap:label="Dyn. Action Control" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="Edit_ac" Type="Edm.Boolean" sap:label="Dyn. Action Control" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="Preparation_ac" Type="Edm.Boolean" sap:label="Dyn. Action Control" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="Validation_ac" Type="Edm.Boolean" sap:label="Dyn. Action Control" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="PurReqnDescription_fc" Type="Edm.Byte" sap:label="Dyn. Field Control" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="PurReqnSSPRequestor_fc" Type="Edm.Byte" sap:label="Dyn. Field Control" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="PurchaseRequisition" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" MaxLength="10" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Purchase requisition" sap:quickinfo="Purchase requisition number" sap:value-list="standard"/>
<Property Name="PurReqnDescription" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="40" sap:field-control="PurReqnDescription_fc" sap:label="Purchase Requisition Name" sap:quickinfo="Short Text"/>
<Property Name="PurReqnSSPRequestor" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="60" sap:field-control="PurReqnSSPRequestor_fc" sap:label="Requestor" sap:value-list="standard"/>
<Property Name="PurReqnSSPAuthor" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="12" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Author" sap:quickinfo="Author of Requisition"/>
<Property Name="PurchaseRequisitionType" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="4" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Document Type" sap:quickinfo="Purchase Requisition Document Type"/>
<Property Name="CreationDate" Type="Edm.DateTime" Precision="0" sap:display-format="Date" sap:label="Created On"/>
<Property Name="EmployeeFullName" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="80" sap:label="Requested By" sap:quickinfo="Full Name of Person"/>
<Property Name="PurReqnOrigin" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="1" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Creation indicator" sap:quickinfo="Creation indicator (purchase requisition/schedule lines)"/>
<Property Name="PurReqnLifeCycleStatus" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="2" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="LifeCycle Status" sap:quickinfo="Purchase requistion status" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="PurReqnLifeCycleStatusName" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="60" sap:label="Status" sap:quickinfo="Short Text for Fixed Values" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="NumberOfItems" Type="Edm.Int32" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="TotalNetAmount" Type="Edm.Decimal" Precision="16" Scale="3" sap:unit="Currency" sap:label="Total Net Value" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="Currency" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="5" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false" sap:semantics="currency-code"/>
<Property Name="IsSrchEnabled" Type="Edm.Boolean" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Hide Search Bar" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false"/>
<Property Name="IsExtPurgScenario" Type="Edm.Boolean" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Is External Purch." sap:quickinfo="Indicator for external purchasing scenario" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="IsOnBehalfCart" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="1" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Shop On Behalf Ind." sap:quickinfo="Shop on behalf indicator"/>
<Property Name="PurReqnIsCopyDraft" Type="Edm.Boolean" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Draft Is Copied" sap:quickinfo="Draft is copied from active document"/>
<Property Name="BusinessUser" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="12" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="User ID"/>
<Property Name="PurReqnIsCreatedInExpertMode" Type="Edm.Boolean" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="PR in Expert Mode" sap:quickinfo="PR Created in Expert Mode"/>
<Property Name="AccountAssignmentCategory" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="1" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Acct Assignment Cat." sap:quickinfo="Account Assignment Category" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="AcctAssignmentCategoryName" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="20" sap:label="AcctAssgntCateg Desc" sap:quickinfo="Account Assignment Category Description" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="PrimaryCostObject" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="30" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Primary Cost Object" sap:quickinfo="Account Assignment Primary Cost Object" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="PrimaryCostObjectName" Type="Edm.String" MaxLength="60" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Prim. Cost Obj. Name" sap:quickinfo="Account Assignment Primary Cost Object Name" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="DeliveryDurationInDays" Type="Edm.Decimal" Precision="3" Scale="0" sap:label="Delivery time (days)" sap:quickinfo="Delivery time in days" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="DeliveryTime" Type="Edm.Decimal" Precision="3" Scale="0" sap:label="Delivery time (days)" sap:quickinfo="Delivery time in days" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="DeliveryDate" Type="Edm.DateTime" Precision="0" sap:display-format="Date" sap:label="Delivery date" sap:quickinfo="Item delivery date" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false" sap:sortable="false" sap:filterable="false"/>
<Property Name="HasDraftEntity" Type="Edm.Boolean" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Has Draft" sap:heading="" sap:quickinfo="" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false"/>
<Property Name="DraftUUID" Type="Edm.Guid" Nullable="false" sap:label="Key" sap:heading="" sap:quickinfo="" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false"/>
<Property Name="DraftEntityCreationDateTime" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Precision="7" sap:label="Draft Created On" sap:heading="" sap:quickinfo="" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false"/>
<Property Name="DraftEntityLastChangeDateTime" Type="Edm.DateTimeOffset" Precision="7" sap:label="Draft Last Changed On" sap:heading="" sap:quickinfo="" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false"/>
<Property Name="HasActiveEntity" Type="Edm.Boolean" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Has active" sap:heading="" sap:quickinfo="" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false"/>
<Property Name="IsActiveEntity" Type="Edm.Boolean" Nullable="false" sap:display-format="UpperCase" sap:label="Is active" sap:heading="" sap:quickinfo="" sap:creatable="false" sap:updatable="false"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="DraftAdministrativeData" Relationship="MMPUR_REQ_GPR_MAINTAIN_SRV.assoc_76A4502D0F516EE52DD3CBBBE346E4D9" FromRole="FromRole_assoc_76A4502D0F516EE52DD3CBBBE346E4D9" ToRole="ToRole_assoc_76A4502D0F516EE52DD3CBBBE346E4D9"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="SiblingEntity" Relationship="MMPUR_REQ_GPR_MAINTAIN_SRV.assoc_3CC1A0E5A29B95AA58385E4B4E670133" FromRole="FromRole_assoc_3CC1A0E5A29B95AA58385E4B4E670133" ToRole="ToRole_assoc_3CC1A0E5A29B95AA58385E4B4E670133"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="to_GuidedProcmtReqnDelivAddr" Relationship="MMPUR_REQ_GPR_MAINTAIN_SRV.assoc_ABFFAA8E73382AA60F058244C4ABBB35" FromRole="FromRole_assoc_ABFFAA8E73382AA60F058244C4ABBB35" ToRole="ToRole_assoc_ABFFAA8E73382AA60F058244C4ABBB35"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="to_GuidedProcmtReqnUserDefaults" Relationship="MMPUR_REQ_GPR_MAINTAIN_SRV.assoc_1579C23A5F4ED87BDC6BD58F2005A338" FromRole="FromRole_assoc_1579C23A5F4ED87BDC6BD58F2005A338" ToRole="ToRole_assoc_1579C23A5F4ED87BDC6BD58F2005A338"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="to_Purchaserequisitionitem_Wd" Relationship="MMPUR_REQ_GPR_MAINTAIN_SRV.assoc_3F09BE43BBC7F408BF50540B885968FB" FromRole="FromRole_assoc_3F09BE43BBC7F408BF50540B885968FB" ToRole="ToRole_assoc_3F09BE43BBC7F408BF50540B885968FB"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="to_PurReqnEmplByCoOfAuthorVH" Relationship="MMPUR_REQ_GPR_MAINTAIN_SRV.assoc_F51CC3D827FD02E8485693F0D8E2BECB" FromRole="FromRole_assoc_F51CC3D827FD02E8485693F0D8E2BECB" ToRole="ToRole_assoc_F51CC3D827FD02E8485693F0D8E2BECB"/>
<NavigationProperty Name="to_SSPReqnConfiguration" Relationship="MMPUR_REQ_GPR_MAINTAIN_SRV.assoc_8453857C8C3E316B4D665A8FF57BD512" FromRole="FromRole_assoc_8453857C8C3E316B4D665A8FF57BD512" ToRole="ToRole_assoc_8453857C8C3E316B4D665A8FF57BD512"/>
</EntityType>
```

Here the problem is for navigation

```
<NavigationProperty Name="to_GuidedProcmtReqnDelivAddr" Relationship="MMPUR_REQ_GPR_MAINTAIN_SRV.assoc_ABFFAA8E73382AA60F058244C4ABBB35" FromRole="FromRole_assoc_ABFFAA8E73382AA60F058244C4ABBB35" ToRole="ToRole_assoc_ABFFAA8E73382AA60F058244C4ABBB35"/>

<Association Name="assoc_ABFFAA8E73382AA60F058244C4ABBB35" sap:content-version="1">
<End Type="MMPUR_REQ_GPR_MAINTAIN_SRV.C_GuidedProcmtReqnHdrTPType" Multiplicity="1" Role="FromRole_assoc_ABFFAA8E73382AA60F058244C4ABBB35"/>
<End Type="MMPUR_REQ_GPR_MAINTAIN_SRV.C_GuidedProcmtReqnDelivAddrType" Multiplicity="0..1" Role="ToRole_assoc_ABFFAA8E73382AA60F058244C4ABBB35"/>
</Association>
```

Comment: Can you pls provide the complete stack trace?

Comment: I am not able to get the complete stack trace, as I am getting NullPointerException at ODataQueryResult.java ->  inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(); , here  httpResponse.getEntity() is returning Null for 204 No Content response, and when getContent() is tried to invoke its throwing NullPointerException.

Comment: I have added the metadata  for the entity. While I was debugging I found that entitymetadata is null for this scenario in internalExecute method of ODataQuery class, hence there is error while creating new ODataQueryResult(entitymetadata, httpResponse, isMediaRequest); at line 247 ODataQuery class(inside private internalExecute method)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your detailed question.

It seems like you indeed have found a bug in one of the indirectly consumed components related to SAP Cloud SDK. I have created an incident (#1970496164) in the ticketing system. It's not clear when precisely this *NullPointerException* will be fixed, hopefully in one of the next upcoming versions.

In the meantime, I'd suggest using the [Try API](https://www.vavr.io/vavr-docs/#_try) of the VAVR library as a workaround - to handle the error at runtime.

```java
import io.vavr.control.Try;

// ...

@Nonnull
HeaderCDSForPRForGuidedBuying requisitionHeader;

@Nullable
GuidedProcurementDeliveryAddressAtHeader requisitionHeaderAddress;

// tolerant error handling
requisitionHeaderAddress = Try.of(requisitionHeader::getGuidedProcmtReqnDelivAddrOrFetch).getOrNull();

return S4ToGBServiceMapper.mapToRequisitionHeader(requisitionHeader, requisitionHeaderAddress);
```

(assuming your `mapToRequisitionHeader` method expects the second parameter to be `@Nullable`)

Add the dependency to your pom:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.vavr</groupId>
  <artifactId>vavr</artifactId>
  <version>0.10.2</version>
</dependency>
```

As an alternative to my proposal, you could just use the *bulky* try-catch block of course.